# How to add a progress bar to a command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

Im writing a script that removes user profiles with in powershel  using this command

`Get-WMIObject -class Win32_UserProfile | Where {(!$_.Special) -and (!$_.loaded)} | Remove-WmiObject`

How would i go about adding a progress bar to the command, so that when one profile has been removed it would go up type of thing, this is part of a gui program and the console is hidden

Comment: You can use `write-progress`

Comment: how would i go about adding ```write-progress``` to the command, as this command in its self is recursive, the only documentation for this is with it in loops of some form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a loop to go through each user profile if you're going to use `Write-Progress`. Something along the lines of.

```
$profiles = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_UserProfile | Where {(!$_.Special) -and (!$_.loaded)}
$num_profiles = $profiles.Count
Function Remove_Prof
{
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt $num_profiles; $i++)
        { 
        Remove-WMIObject $profiles[$i]
        Start-Sleep -m 1000  
        Write-Progress -Activity 'Removing Profiles' -Status "Deleted $i out of $num_profiles profiles" -PercentComplete (($i/$num_profiles) * 100)
        
        }
}

Remove_Prof;
```

You can replace/remove the sleep call - I just had that because in my test I didn't actually delete the profile(s).